# Why does my jQuery Ajax response include post array first?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery Ajax POST request going to a PHP site with some data added in the _POST array.
I can't figure out why in the Ajax response I seem to get the _POST array returned to me before my JSON response. All I want is the second line in the response below.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",  
 url: "site.php",  
 data: { requestType : 'someType', table : 'someTable' },
 success: function(data){ 
  alert(data);
 },
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert(errorThrown); //or whatever
 }
});
```

The response:

```
array(2) { ["requestType"]=> string(6) "someType" ["table"]=> string(17)    "someTable" } 
[{"User":1,"User":"xxx","Pd":"xxx","Name":"xxx","Age":xx,"Occupation":"xxx","Description":"xxx"}]
```

The PHP

```
$result = $stmt->execute(); 

//put the results in to the $result variable
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                     
    array_push($result_array, $row);
}

echo json_encode($result_array);
```

Comment: mmmmm take a look of what you printing out on your php file, because this is not JQuery things.

Comment: Show us your php code. How are you returning the response ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to populate a variable `$item` with values from the `$row` variable.

```
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
        $item['Pd'] = $row['Pd'];  
        $item['Name'] = $row['Name'];            
        array_push($result_array, $item);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try change this code:
`success: function(data){ 
alert(data);
}`

to

`success: function(response){ 
alert(response);
}`

Remember, clear cache.